# How can I temporarily disable an element's CSS hover-triggered animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Consider this slider:

```js
$(function() {
  var $volumeBar = $('#Volume-Bar');
  var $volumeContainer = $('#Volume-Container');
  var $value = $('.value');

  $volumeContainer.on('mousedown', function(event) {
    var height = $volumeContainer.height();
    var top = $volumeContainer.position().top;
    var startingCoord = event.clientY - top;
    var currentCoord;
    var percent;
    var difference;
    seekingVol = true;
    $volumeBar.css({
      'background-color': '#dcb311',
    });
    $volumeContainer.on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
      if (seekingVol) {
        seekingVol = false;
        $volumeBar.css({
          'background-color': '',
        });
      }
    });
    $volumeContainer.on('mousemove', function(event) {
      if (seekingVol) {
        currentCoord = event.clientY - top;
        percent = ((height - currentCoord) / height) * 100;
        $volumeBar.finish();
        $volumeBar.css({
          'height': percent + '%'
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:700);
#Volume-Container {
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #0e2030;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#Volume-Bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #6ab2f2;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

#Volume-Bar:hover {
  background-color: #dcb311;
  animation: Vert-Bounce 0.6s;
}

@keyframes Vert-Bounce {
  0% {
    transform: height(1);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleY(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scaleY(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Volume-Container">
  <div id="Volume-Bar"></div>
</div>
```

Notice the bounce animation on the bar on hover?

When the user pulls the bar upward, the mouse exits the element due to the lag between the bar's scaling and the movement of the mouse. When the element catches up to the mouse or the user pulls back downward, another hover event is fired as the mouse re-enters the element. This triggers the bounce animation multiple times as the user drags the bar. I want to disable this animation on `mousedown` and re-activate it on `mouseup`.

How can I do this?

Comment: From a UI/UX perspective, I don't think that having this animation in the first place is a good idea. If the height has some sort of meaningful representation, then an animation to get the user's attention should not involve that property. Use color or even width in the animation, and you can avoid this issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, the bouncing animation occurs on dragging.
And this is the problem.

I tried something that may be of interest.
I used `mouseover` and `mouseout` events in event listeners functions... Instead of the CSS `hover` to handle the bouncing effect.

```
$(function() {

  var $volumeBar = $('#Volume-Bar');
  var $volumeContainer = $('#Volume-Container');
  var $value = $('.value');

  $volumeBar.on('mouseover', function(event) {      // Added this event function
    $volumeBar.css({"background-color":"#dcb311","animation":"Vert-Bounce 0.6s"});
  });

  $volumeBar.on('mouseout', function(event) {       // Added this event function
    $volumeBar.css({"background-color":"#6ab2f2","animation":"initial"});
  });

  $volumeContainer.on('mousedown', function(event) {
    var height = $volumeContainer.height();
    var top = $volumeContainer.position().top;
    var startingCoord = event.clientY - top;
    var currentCoord;
    var percent;
    var difference;
    seekingVol = true;
    $volumeBar.css({
      'background-color': '#dcb311',
    });
    $volumeContainer.on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
      if (seekingVol) {
        seekingVol = false;
        $volumeBar.css({
          'background-color': '',
        });
      }
    });
    $volumeContainer.on('mousemove', function(event) {
      if (seekingVol) {
        currentCoord = event.clientY - top;
        percent = ((height - currentCoord) / height) * 100;
        $volumeBar.finish();
        $volumeBar.css({
          'height': percent + '%'
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

See Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/8fpqxhoe/

**NOTE:**
I added a 6px padding to it: In order to prevent the mouse from mouseout on drag.
This *may* be a problem...